# Azure Active directory return 403 as Access denied

Tags: python, azure, graph-explorer

I am new to using this type of trying to get the user details in my org using python flask server by hitting the
URL : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
Request headers:
'Content-Type': "application/json", 'Authorization': accessToken
Response:

## Access Denied

The page you requested has been blocked

any suggestions please?

From the graph URL , able to get the response from python code base we got the Access Denied.
method in python:

```
enter code here
```

def get_user_details_(access_token: str):
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json",
'Authorization': access_token
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
print("response **** ", response.text)
response = response.json() if response else {}
return response

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Jq2.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: def get_user_details_(access_token: str):
        url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
        headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json", 
     'Authorization': access_token
                  }
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        print("response **** ", response.text)
        response = response.json() if response else {}
        return response

Comment: this is the GET method call to get the user details

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the above issue, We can follow the below workaround;

- Make sure that you have following permissions given for your application so that, while calling the API it can able to read and give the desired result.

[image]

***OUTPUT RESULT FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

For complete setup please refr this **BLOG**[***|Querying Microsoft Graph API with Python***](https://towardsdatascience.com/querying-microsoft-graph-api-with-python-269118e8180c) by @*Ephraim Mwai*.

Comment: I am able to get data from graph URL from microsoft graph URL, but I am unable to get the python flask get API

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
It is related to Proxy. We need to add proxy details to request object.

***proxyDict = {
"http": "http proxy address",
"https": "https proxy address"
}***

response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers, ***proxies=proxyDict***, verify=False)